# Use of Validation Group in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I can't not to use Validation Group in asp.net c#.

I have searched solution in Google without success.

In this simple form asp.net the TextBox **pcs** is always validated even when the value is null or the value is not a number.

My code asp.net below, what is wrong?

HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:TextBox ID="pcs" runat="server" Width="100" CssClass="ddl_Class" ValidationGroup="First"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="pcs"
                ErrorMessage="PCS !" Text="***" Display="None" ValidationGroup="First"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorPcs" runat="server" ControlToValidate="pcs"
                ErrorMessage="PCS only number" Text="***" Display="None" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ValidationGroup="First"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/save_button.gif" OnClientClick="return confirm('Confirm ?');" ValidationGroup="First" CausesValidation="true" />

            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="First" runat="Server" ShowMessageBox="true" />

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 1**

The problem is the OnClientClick event.

If delete this event in asp:ImageButton the validation group working.

Why?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:TextBox ID="pcs" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="pcs"
                ErrorMessage="PCS !" Text="***" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="pcs"
                ErrorMessage="PCS only number" Text="***" Display="None" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/save_button.gif" />

        </div>

        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="First" runat="Server"
            ShowMessageBox="true" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, what are the cases on which you don't want to use the `RequiredFieldValidator`?

Comment: I have to build a form with some required fields and other not required.
I'm trying with one required field but this does not work,

Comment: Nothing looks wrong to me. it is doing what is supposed to do. YOu have 2 validators on pcs, one as required and other as number.

Comment: Please see **EDIT** in my first question, I have found the problem, why?

Comment: This is because the client event always comes first before the server event. So if the client event is triggered, the server event will not continue. Unless you put  `return;` in the end of your client function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnClientClick` is a useful property introduced in ASP.NET 2.0 that allows us to add some client-side behavior to button control. Using is as simple as providing the script to be called when a button is clicked by a user:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Save" 
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" />
```

The problem is that if you use it like that, client-side validation won't fire. Looking at the rendered HTML quickly explains the situation:

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(...)"
```

As you can see, the validation doesn't even have a chance to fire (which happens when `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions` is called).

Solving the issue is simple (or not). All that has to be done is a little change in our OnClientClick script (a piece of code found somewhere on the Internet):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Save" 
    OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;" />
```

Now we only return false (preventing the submit) in case a user didn't confirm the action, otherwise, the rest of the script will be called thus firing validation.

The reason I said that it may not be a simple issue is the fact, that the validation happens AFTER the confirmation, which is not the best thing in my opinion. Why ask the user about saving his data if there are still errors on the form, of which we will inform him after he confirms that he wants to save it?

After analyzing a bit, the code responsible for dealing with `OnClientScript`, I have come to a conclusion, that solving this problem is not an easy task. It would require some dirty hacks on the server side to make it pretty or calling validation routines on the client, before displaying the confirmation dialog (keeping in mind that checking if there are validation routines present at all is necessary in this case).

Used From  : http://vaultofthoughts.net/OnClientClickBreaksValidation.aspx